# Are attacks on characters stuck in a web at advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage

When a character is stuck in a web (such as from a web spell) do attacks against them gain advantage in D&D 5e?

The spell itself doesn’t say anything about attacks on the character, and in particular whether ranged or attacks within 5 feet gain advantage.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The spell applies a condition that determines that the attacks do indeed get advantage:

> On a failed save, the creature is **restrained** as long as it remains in
>   the webs (PHB 288, emphasis mine)

Restrained means, among other things:

> Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and
>   the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage. (PHB 291)

The web from a giant spider imposes the same condition:

> Web (Recharge 5-6). Ranged Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, range 30f60 ft.,
>   one creature. Hit: The target is restrained by webbing. (MM 328)

It is not explicitly stated that *all* webs restrain those caught in them, but it seems most of them use that condition.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes

Webs can be found in the DMG 105 as a Dungeon Hazard. It states the following effects:

> ... a creature entering the webbed area for the first time on a turn or starting its turn there must succeed on a DC 12 Dexterity Saving Throw or become **restrained** by the webs.

*Restrained* is one of the conditions listed in PHB 292:

> - Attack rolls against this creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.

Unless otherwise stated, all the effects of a condition are applied in full. In the case of this scenario, any attack on the stuck character will be at advantage (among other nasty effects).